# Input with Width 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a search bar but I dont want it like this. It is broken atm.

I should only see the span icon and when i hover it, the input should slide aligned with the span.

The problem is that I can't seem to hide the input. Why `width: 0;` doesn't work for the input?

```css
.navbar {
background-color:#aaa
}

.search {
    width: 230px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.search button {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
.search button span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #fff;
}
.search input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    float: Left;
    margin-left: 180px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.search:hover input,
.search input:focus {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar">
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm float-left" maxlength="64" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should remove the padding and border too when collapsed to fully hide the input

Comment: `opacity:0;` for `.search input` and `opacity:1;` for `.search:hover input` . See the result below in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with visibility hidden and visible after hover.

[Example for you code](https://codepen.io/drobke/pen/zpgNXp)

```
.search input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.search input:hover{
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it easy by adding the opacity 0/1  `opacity:0;` for `.search input` and `opacity:1;` for `.search:hover input` . See the result below

```css
    .navbar {
    background-color:#aaa
    }
    
    .search {
        width: 230px;
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 22px;
    }
    .search button {
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 0;
    }
    .search button span {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .search input {
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        float: Left;
        margin-left: 180px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
        border-radius: 3px !important;
        opacity:0; // <-- this
    }
    
    .search:hover input,
    .search input:focus {
        width: 200px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        opacity:1; // <-- and this
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar">
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm float-left" maxlength="64" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create this effect using `flexbox` instead of absolute positioning.

For the input to be completely hidden, you need to hide the `border` and `padding` initially, and add them back on hover.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #aaa
}

.search {
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: flex;
}

.search button {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.search button span {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fff;
}

.search input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 180px;
}

.search:hover input,
.search input:focus {
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
  border: 2px inset;
  border-radius: 3px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm float-left" maxlength="64" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue `input` tag `width:0px` still showed the `input` tag with 1 or 2 pixel width.

It worked in some browsers but not **Chrome** or new **Edge Chromium**.

For my solution if I put the `input` in a `div` and set the `div` `width:0px`.
It hid the `input` but still allow it to receive events (I need this because events do not work if you set the `input` to `display:hidden`, but want the `input` not to show)

Answer (score 0):

Use keyframes and animations instead.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```css
.navbar {
background-color:#aaa
}

.search {
    width: 230px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 22px;
}
.search button {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
.search button span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #fff;
}
.search input {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    width: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 180px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.search:hover input,
.search input:focus {
    margin-left: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    animation-name: expand-search;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    width:200px;
}

@keyframes expand-search {
    from {width: 0px;}
    to {width: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar">
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm float-left" maxlength="64" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
```